# Error when starting a new bash session from eval

Tags: bash, eval

i get this new error when i log into bash and i cannot seem to trace it.

```
Last login: Thu Apr 14 00:32:33 on ttys000
-bash: eval: line 40: unexpected EOF while looking for `]]'
-bash: eval: line 41: syntax error: unexpected end of file
user:~ user$
```

Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: Try running `script -c "bash -vxl"` Exit the started bash & check generated file named `typescript`.

Comment: -c is an illegal option of the script command. Didn't work for me :(

Comment: maybe there is something wrong in your .bashrc file ..

Comment: Then start `script`. After you get shell prompt, run `bash -vxl`. After getting the next prompt, press `^D` twice. Check the typescript file generated.

Comment: @ClaudioM I have checked my .bashrc file and it doesn't even have 40 lines, so i doubt it's  that.

Comment: @anishsane Ihave done as you say and it generated a ~12k lines typescript. Do you have any advice as to how to debug? (it's too long for me to paste here).Thank you!!

Comment: Do you see the failure print in the file generated? Then you can see which sourced script & which line has that syntax error.

Comment: could you please copy and paste your .bashrc file?